# How can we pay the Canada visa application fee after the first payment failed?

Tags: canada, online-resources, paperwork, payment

I am applying for a Canada visitor visa online

When I reach the payment screen, there are 2 options.

- Online banking
- Visa, MasterCard etc debit card

I choose `Online Banking,` but on that next page, my bank was not listed.

I clicked on `Cancel` and thought I could return to the payment option, and do it by debit card.

Now it's doesn't give me any way go back to the payment screen pay the fees. How or when can I pay? Will there be an extra charge, if we use debit card not from a bank in Canada?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wait 60-120 minutes, the system will cancel the payment and you will be able to repeat it once again.

The same procedure should be made if the Visa/Mastercard payment has failed.